# How to add ImageView to a NavigationDrawer along with a ListView

Tags: android

[image]
I am using a NavigationDrawer in my Android application that shows items in a ListView. What I want to do, is to add a ImageView element programmatically. 
My NavigationDrawer layout (`activity_navigation.xml`) is as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_linear"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/navigation_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have a ListView item layout (`listview_item_row.xml`), too. It is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_drawer_list_item_selector"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my NavigationActivity, I use the following code to dynamically populate ListView items:

```
mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.app_navigation_items);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_linear);
ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[6];
drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_speedometer, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[0]);
drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_place, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[1]);
drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_price, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[2]);
drawerItem[3] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[3]);
drawerItem[4] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_about, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[4]);
drawerItem[5] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_logout, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[5]);
DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);        
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

So, how can I achieve the ImageView along with the name, and picture inside it in my NavigationDrawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a View on top of a ListView with [`ListView.addHeaderView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)). This will make the picture and the name to scroll along with the `ListView`.

Example with the headerView :

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row);
((ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon)).setImageBitmap(...);
((TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textviewName)).setText(userName);
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

If you don't want the picture and the name to scroll, just add your views just above the ListView in `activity_navigation.xml`

Comment: And how do I assign the picture and name to them? I want them to be dynamic, i.e. a user's picture and their name they've provided while signing up.

Comment: Just like any other View. Use findViewById() in your activity, store the View and update it whenever the data is ready.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code for this? Right now, I'm playing with static data and passing it programmatically.
Kind of a newbie when it comes to Android.

Comment: Edited my answer with a sample.

Comment: I tried that but got the following error
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.android/com.project.android.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: Ok, I looked a little bit and modified 
`View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row);`
to
`View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, null);` and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/activity_base">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        style="@style/ProgressBarblitzprogress"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dlinlayout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/ehog_green"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_line"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/current_country"
            android:src="@drawable/_cf_big_empty"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/curent_settlem"
            android:text="@string/unknown_place"
            style="@style/current_settlem_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_country"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/curent_address"
            android:text="@string/unknown_address"
            style="@style/current_address_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_country"
            android:layout_below="@+id/curent_settlem"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/current_sunangle_pic"
            android:layout_below="@+id/curent_address"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_country"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_sunangle"
            android:text="@string/unknown_place_sunangle"
            style="@style/current_address_sunangle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/current_sunangle_pic"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_country"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/menuitem_selector"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is an example for custom navigation drawer, the main layout of the navigation is `dlinlayout`, the header is the `RelativeLayout` inside this. And I have also implemented a custom list adapter to `left_drawer`, to show the menu with icons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, ehog, but I'd like to achieve the solution programmatically not by adding static views to my layout files.